# Selenium Web driver Issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Recently my chrome version has been updated from version 75 to Version 77.0.3865.120(64-bit). My program used to work with Version 75 and chrome driver related to 75 and now that my chrome browser has been updated to 77.0.3865.120(64-bit) i am getting below error message

```
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
Additional information: invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions**
```

Here is my code :

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.AddArguments("window-size=800,600");
 chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
 capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, chromeOptions);
 using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("local path to driver", chromeOptions)) -- error at this line
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Have you updated chromedriver to v77 - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/?

Comment: So update chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome 77.00 version, need to download **Chromedriver** 77.00 here is the link: 
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/